how to make the dependency in the compileClasspath
I have a Gradle project named A, which depends on a JAR file named B.jar. Additionally, B.jar has a dependency on C.jar, and project A also directly depends on C.jar.
When I add B.jar as a dependency in my build.gradle file within VSCode, I expect C.jar to be automatically included in project A due to B's dependency on it. However, when I execute the gradle build command, it prompts that C.jar is missing. Why the C.jar not in the compileClasspath? Do I have to explicitly add C.jar to my build.gradle file as well?
Below is the result when I run the gradlew dependencies command:
compileClasspath
\--- B  
  
runtimeClasspath  
\--- B  
     \--- C

I have check the other library, then can include the dependency in the project. for example, AWS SDK
+--- software.amazon.awssdk:s3 -> 2.29.1
|    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:aws-xml-protocol:2.29.1
|    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:aws-query-protocol:2.29.1
|    |    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:protocol-core:2.29.1


You don't have to explicitly add it. The pom.xml file for B should tell Gradle to also pick up C. Maybe if you say what B and C are I can check it for you.
